# Listing all routes in compojure

Tags: clojure, compojure

How can I list all the routes on a handler function?  I'm looking for behavior similar to rails' `rake routes`. For example:

```
(defroutes foo-routes
    (GET "/foo/:foo-id"
        [foo-id]
            "bar response")
    (GET "/bar/:bar-id"
        [bar-id]
            "foo response"))
```

Is it then possible to extract a map from foo-bar-routes containing the following?

```
{:GET "/foo/:foo-id"
 :GET "/bar/:bar-id"}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible. [defroutes](https://weavejester.github.io/compojure/compojure.core.html#var-defroutes) is a macro that returns a ring handler. [GET](https://weavejester.github.io/compojure/compojure.core.html#var-GET) is a macro that returns a route. Route is again just a function that calls related handler only if method and path are matching. So in the end your foo-routes is just a clojure function that is composed of other functions defined by your routes and it doesn't maintain such map. If you need to get such map, maybe you can maintain it in your code yourself and generate routes out of this map.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is quite old but I had the same question and could resolve it by myself, here's what I've got:

Assuming you defined your API this way:

```clj
(def my-api (compojure.api.api/api ...))
```

Then you can easily list the routes you defined that way:

```clj
(->> (.-get-routes my-api {})
     (map (juxt second first)))
```